# How to only see GNU/libre extension inside VsCodium?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gnu, privacy

I've installed `vscodium`,  In the Extension part, There are a lot of extensions, but I am worried if I again install non-free extension. Instead, I want to install only opensource / libre ones , How should I search for that thank you.

Answer (score 0):

disclaimer: I'm not using VsCode nor VsCodium or Theia but only vim...

First, you can't use Microsoft Marketplace Extension with VsCodium according to the Term of Use...

> Marketplace
> Offerings are intended for use only with Visual Studio Products and Services and you may only install
> and use Marketplace Offerings with Visual Studio Products and Services.

ref: https://cdn.vsassets.io/v/M146_20190123.39/_content/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-Marketplace-Terms-of-Use.pdf

So you may use Open-VSX https://open-vsx.org/
If you clic on an extension e.g. https://open-vsx.org/extension/redhat/java it seems you can see the license and the source repository...